# How to stop and start function app with delay

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, servicebus

I have a service bus queue trigger azure function (v4) where when a particular message comes, I need to stop the function and restart after some time specified in the message itself. In case of non function apps, I am simply closing the queueClient and recreating it after that specified time. Please help me find a way to do the same in function apps. I need solutions for two scenarios, one, when the function is deployed on azure function apps. Two, more importantly **when it is deployed on Azure Kubernetes service.**

Comment: You could store a boolean in a database which keeps track whether the function is enabled or disabled and use that to decide whether to execute the function or not

Comment: But how would I control the trigger? I don't want the function to trigger at all for that period of time.

Comment: That would mean disabling the function, which you can do by changing an app setting AzureWebJobs.<FUNCTION_NAME>.Disabled, but that would require you to use another function to do this, because after it’s disabled you wont be able to call it anymore or you use a master key to trigger the disabled function and enable it again

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Selmir Aljic , that you can use a variable to know about the functions status.
To do that you need another function to make the function app in running state and you can disable the required function by using `AzureWebJobs.<FUNCTION_NAME>.Disabled` : true .

So that, you can enable it whenever required function or use the master key for enable-disable the function.

References:

- [How to disable functions in Azure Functions | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=portal)

Comment: This doesn't work for functions deployed in Azure Kubernetes Service. All the methods mentioned in the reference link also don't work.